# Sorting bars and legend in Seaborn stacked histplot without rearranging the data incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating a stacked histogram using Seaborn, however I am having issues with sorting the bars in ascending/descending order.

I am using the hue_order to try order the bars in ascending order, but am not having much luck. I've messed around with the hue_order quite a lot, trying inplace=False combined with a .index, but that did not have much luck either.

Answer (score 2):

For the `hue_order`, you'd need to take the index of the `value_sort` dataframe.  But, as you seem to want an alphabetic sort (and not a value sort), you can use the sorted unique names of the 'model' column instead.

To sort the x values, you can make the airline names categorical and set a specific order.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('acrftreg.csv')

airline_names = ["Qantas", "Express Freighters Australia", "Network Aviation", "Sunstate Airlines",
                 "National Jet Systems", "Eastern Australia Airlines", "Jetstar"]
airline_long_names = ['QANTAS AIRWAYS LIMITED', 'EXPRESS FREIGHTERS AUSTRALIA PTY LIMITED', 'NETWORK AVIATION PTY LTD',
                      'SUNSTATE AIRLINES (QLD) PTY. LIMITED', 'NATIONAL JET SYSTEMS PTY LTD',
                      'EASTERN AUSTRALIA AIRLINES PTY. LIMITED', 'JETSTAR AIRWAYS PTY LIMITED']

# take the subset of the desired airlines
data = data[data['regopName'].isin(airline_long_names)]
# replace the original names with the names to display
data['regopName'] = data['regopName'].replace(airline_long_names, airline_names)
# make the column categorical, using the order of the `value_counts`
data['regopName'] = pd.Categorical(data['regopName'], data['regopName'].value_counts(sort=True).index)

# use the alphabetical order of the model to order the hue values
hue_order = data['Model'].unique()
hue_order.sort()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 6))
sns.histplot(data, x="regopName", hue="Model", multiple="stack", edgecolor=".3", linewidth=.5, hue_order=hue_order, ax=ax)
ax.margins(x=0.01)
ax.set_xlabel('')
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stacked sns.histplot with hue and x ordering]